# Image Comparison - Appium - iOS - c#

Tags: c#, image, appium

I Automate iOS apps with c# using visual studio mac as an editor with Nunit framework

I am trying to find a way to use Image recognition using find element by image.

I Installed openCVSharp library and the created a folder where i can save the images and the image is saved as .png file, I capture the image path and then convert the image to Base64 encoded string. And now i try to use the FindElementByImage(base64Image), it does not click the element on the screen.

The Appium server quits on me, It does not even consider “Image” as a valid locator in the logs, I have read in some of the articles that settings API is needed to control the Appium server. Can someone help on how is settings API configured in the project along with the code

There are articles that explains Image recognition with OpenCV4nodejs and Java, But i am not able to do that with c#.

Comment: Show your code please.